# How to log out from google web session automatically

Tags: javascript

Need some help, is there any way to *Sign Out All Gmail web session* automatically?, like maybe every day, so in the morning i have to login first.

Answer (score 0):

Site data is stored in the form of cookies, which usually hold a login token. If you want to remove them every day, probably the easiest way is to use something like Firefox's 'forget' button. Most browsers have a mode where they will delete your cookies upon exit, but don't generally have time based deletion.
This article talks about how to set up all of the major browsers:
https://www.pcworld.com/article/2846020/how-to-automatically-delete-your-cookies-every-time-you-close-your-browser.html